# Fonts in gardr banner validator

Tags: html, css, validation, banner

I have fonts in folder with index.html.
I want to add fonts into banner. Locally works, but validator has error..
Please explain me what i doing wrong.. (I was trying use url('/col...'), url('col...'))
I will very grateful if anyone help me fast..

```
@font-face {
            font-family: 'colaborate';
            src: url('./colabthi-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('./colabthi-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('./colabthi-webfont.svg#colaborate-thinregular') format('svg');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }
```

> There are 3 request errors
>
> ```
> colabthi-webfont.woff
> colabthi-webfont.ttf
> colabthi-webfont.svg
> ```

[image]

Comment: You need to let your webserver serve those file types, are you using apache?

Comment: Please don't post images of errors. Please add the text into your question.

Comment: urls in css are relative to the css file. you're saying the woff/tff/svg files are in the same directory as the css file. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, index.html and fonts are siblings.