# Possible javascript malformed / SyntaxError in content from tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, banner

I have page with top iframe(banner in HTML5) and content (ie. slider).
I want to get images from slider on the page and then add two from those into banner (then animate them with css). I tried many options but i have still the same errors..
Please help me..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                    var images = $(parent.window.document.getElementsByTagName('body')).find('#images').find('div');
                    var first = images.eq(0).data('main');
                    var second = images.eq(1).data('main');
                    $('#slider').append("<img id='first-img' src='" + first + "'/><img id='second-img' src='" + second + "'/>");
                    $('body').click(function(){
                        window.open('http://www.google.com/');
                    })
                });
```

Getting errors in http://validator.gardr.org:

- Possible javascript malformed / SyntaxError in content from tag ([user-entry.js:19](http://ads-gardr.gardr.org/user-entry.js?id=7002160b-5dff-4990-909e-2eac66020009-5615-000505&timestamp=1418935832899))
- SyntaxError: Parse error

---

3 error is font ([Font error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555742/fonts-in-gardr-banner-validator))

[image]

Comment: no script errors in this snippet, other than the missing semi colon on the click function, which is only a strict mode warning. Are you sure this is where you are getting errors from?

Comment: https://github.com/inma-no/advertsspec/issues/26